# error when executing a workflow using api

Tags: elsa-workflows

Elsa Version: 2.13

Net: .Net 6

---

When i try to execute a workflow definition i get the follwoing Error:

`{\"Headers\":[{\"Key\":\"Content-Type\",\"Value\":[\"application/json; charset=utf-8\"]}]}`
in the request i insert a context_id and correlation_id to values I can query on does this affect the execution?

```
Elsa.Server.Api.Endpoints.Workflows.ExecuteWorkflowDefinitionRequestModel request = new Elsa.Server.Api.Endpoints.Workflows.ExecuteWorkflowDefinitionRequestModel(null, uid.ToString(), d_uid.ToString(), workflow_input);
string url = $"{workflow_api_url}/workflows/{definition_uid}/execute";
HttpResponseMessage response = await aPIHelper.post(new Uri(url),System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(request));
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
...
```